# How to deploy Rails 2.3.2 app with Capistrano from the top (for FastCGI)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, fastcgi

Disclaimer: i am a noob to Rails and Capistrano (but an intermediate .NET C# developer) trying to learn more.

i have been have the toughest time getting a Capistrano development process set-up.  here's what i have so far for my deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "MyAppName"
set :domain, "domainname"
set :user, "userid" 
set :repository,  "svn+ssh://#{user}@#{domain}/home/#{user}/svn/#{application}/trunk"
set :rails_env, :production
set :chmod755, %w(app config db lib public vendor script tmp public/dispatch.cgi public/dispatch.fcgi public/dispatch.rb)
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :checkout
set :group_writable, false
default_run_options[:pty] = true
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

here's my Capfile:

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
Dir['vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
load 'config/deploy'

namespace :deploy do

  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "#{current_path}/script/process/reaper --dispatcher=dispatch.fcgi"
  end

  desc "Set the proper permissions for directories and files on HostingRails accounts"
  task :after_deploy do
    run(chmod755.collect do |item|
      "chmod 755 #{current_path}/#{item}"
    end.join(" && "))
  end

end
```

1. Rails 2.3.2 doesn't have the script/process directory so the restart task doesn't work at all. How do I fix this?
2. Is there a way to set the RAILS_ENV variable in environment.rb to "production" when the application is deployed ("set :rails_env, :production" does not do it)?
3. Also, am I missing anything else from these 2 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my deploy.rb, which hasn't really been updated in a long time. I run two sed commands to set the environment inside my :after_update_code task. I'm certain there's an easier way to do it, but this is my current method.

```
require 'erb'

before "deploy:setup", :db
after "deploy:update_code", "db:symlink" 
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

def prompt_with_default(var, default)
  set(var) do
    Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "Enter #{var} [#{default}] : "
  end

  set var, default if eval("#{var.to_s}.empty?")
end

default_run_options[:pty] = true 

set :rake, "/usr/local/bin/rake"

set :user, "your username"
set :application, "application name"
set :repository,  "svn repository path"
set :host, "domain name"
set :db_host, "DB host name"
set :db_user, "DB user name"
set :db_prefix, "any DB name prefix your host might require"
set :rails_env, "production"

set :deploy_to, "/home/username/rails/#{host}" # your deployment directory

role :app, host
role :web, host
role :db,  host, :primary => true

set :use_sudo, false
set :checkout, "export"

#
# TASKS
#
desc "Tasks to execute after code update"
task :after_update_code, :roles => [:app, :db, :web] do
  # Make sure we're running in production
  run "sed -i -e '/ENV.*RAILS_ENV/s/# //' #{release_path}/config/environment.rb"
  run "sed -i -e '/ENV.*RAILS_ENV/s/production/#{rails_env}/' #{release_path}/config/environment.rb"

  # Add banned IPs
  deny_lines = []
  File.readlines("#{release_path}/config/banned_ips").each {|ip|
    deny_lines << "deny from #{ip}"
  }

  ip_ban_block = <<EOBAN
# Bannination
order allow,deny
#{deny_lines.join}
allow from all
EOBAN

  run "sed -i -e 's/# BANNED IPS/#{ip_ban_block}/' #{release_path}/public/.htaccess"

  run "chmod +x #{release_path}/script/runner" 
  run "chmod +x #{release_path}/script/process/reaper" 
  run "chmod +x #{release_path}/script/process/spawner" 
  run "chmod 755 #{release_path}/public/dispatch.*" 
end

desc "Restarting after deployment"
task :after_deploy, :roles => [:app, :db, :web] do
  run "cd #{current_path} && rake RAILS_ENV=production db:sessions:clear tmp:clear"
  # fix permissions
  run "dos2unix #{release_path}/public/dispatch.*"
  run "dos2unix #{release_path}/public/.htaccess"
  run "chmod -R 755 #{release_path}"
  run "chmod -R 775 #{release_path}/log #{release_path}/tmp #{release_path}/script"
  run "find #{release_path}/ | xargs touch"
  run "touch #{deploy_to}/current/public/dispatch.fcgi"
end

desc "Restarting after rollback"
task :after_rollback, :roles => [:app, :db, :web] do
  run "touch #{deploy_to}/current/public/dispatch.fcgi"
end

namespace :db do
  desc "Create database yaml in shared path" 
  task :default do
  prompt_with_default(:db_password, "")
  db_config = ERB.new <<-EOF
base: &base
  adapter: mysql
  port: 3306
  host: #{db_host}
  username: #{db_user}
  password: #{db_password}

development:
  database: #{db_prefix}#{application}development
  <<: *base

test:
  database: #{db_prefix}#{application}test
  <<: *base

production:
  database: #{db_prefix}#{application}production
  <<: *base
EOF

    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config" 
    put db_config.result, "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml" 
  end

  desc "Make symlink for database yaml" 
  task :symlink do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml" 
  end
end
```

Once I set up my variables, I have a bash script that runs:

```
svn export $svn_path . --force
cap deploy
```

That'll ask me for my password twice. Once for exporting from SVN, and once as a prompt to automatically generate my database.yml in the shared path.

Comment: your example code helped me understand how to use Capistrano.  i have a very difficult time finding official documentation on how to properly set up a standard deploy.rb & Capfile with variables and tasks for varying scenarios.

Comment: Glad it helped. When I wrote it, the lack of documentation was even more pronounced, and it's cobbled together from bits and pieces I found on the web.

Comment: i'm pretty much doing the same thing.  i'll post my final version as an update to my question soon.

Answer (score 2):

Updated my answer, see #3...

I don't use FastCGI for deployment, but a few things that come to mind:

1. The process scripts have been moved out of Rails core and into [a plugin](http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts/tree/master), which you can grab from GitHub.
2. Looking at my deploy.rb file, you'll likely need to pass the RAILS_ENV environment variable into the script through the command line, similar to:

   `run #{current_path}/script/process/reaper RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} --dispatcher=dispatch.fcgi`
3. EDIT: Actually, it is slightly odd to have your tasks in the Capfile instead of deploy.rb - although looking at [this thread on the Capistrano Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/browse_thread/thread/639aee77b3fbc7b0/6dbb553485434931), it's not completely frowned upon. Up to you/your team, I suppose.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: @Rufo: thx for the tips! i'm using FastCGI right now because i have to pay extra for memory to use a mongrel instance. i'm just trying to get familiar w/ building a rails app right now. if i do more, i'll start using mongrel
1) i actually already tried using the irs_process_scripts plugin but couldn't get it to work
2) which script should i pass it to?
3) hmmm. so is the Capfile essentially just for loading the deploy.rb?  i'll check out the link now.